# How to make git merge include summary of each commit?

Tags: git

For example, I'd like that any time I run `git merge` the merge commit message will include a summary of each commit, not just the "merged branch" message.

Is it possible to configure this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described in [the `git merge` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) (way down in the [CONFIGURATION section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_configuration)):

> merge.log
>
>   In addition to branch names, populate the log message with at most the specified number of one-line descriptions from the actual commits that are being merged. Defaults to false, and true is a synonym for 20.

Comment: to be verbose: `git config merge.log true`

Comment: @g19fanatic: yes, or, `git config merge.log 100` if you don't like the default 20, for instance (pick whatever number you do like—note that this is a maximum; Git will only include as many as there are, or up to this limit, whichever comes first).